# Answer deleted because of SPAM?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

My answers on [How to archive GitHub repositories](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20800/how-to-archive-github-repositories/52294#52294) and [Moving projects away from Github - backing-up / exporting repos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/49090/moving-projects-away-from-github-backing-up-exporting-repos/52292#52292) have been deleted probably because I was promoting a tool/service that I've built myself and didn't disclose it. I don't agree that it is SPAM because it is highly relevant and solves the problem of the user who asked the question. Especially in [How to archive GitHub repositories](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20800/how-to-archive-github-repositories/52294#52294) the user asks for a third party solution. I've edited the answer and disclosed myself as the maker of backhub. I hope that's okay. Can someone please undelete them or should I change anything else in the answer to be accepted?

Answer (score 5):

You should declare your affiliation in the answer.

Once you've edited them, flag them for moderator and one of us (probably not me as I was the one that responded to the original flags) will review them and see if they're OK.

You should also give more details on *why* your tool/service helps.

There's no guarantee that they'll be undeleted of course and if you post again there's every chance the new posts will be flagged as spam as well.

Comment: Just to add that this is also covered (along similar lines) in the Help Centre at the end of [What kind of beahviour is expected of users?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)