# Is it compulsory to mention "I have no affiliation" if one has no affiliations with a product/service/app/etc. one recommends?

Tags: discussion, moderators, deleted-answers

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169928/18147 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20230410002353/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/122414/can-i-permanently-hide-the-youtube-chat-window/169928#comment157477_169928)) got deleted as spam because the author didn't mention "I have no affiliation":

> **You should disclose your affiliation** and describe why you are recommending this tool, among other this. For details see [Best practices for recommending a web app or other tool](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4059/88163). [Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n)**♦**

It's the first time I see an answer being removed because the OP didn't mention "I have no affiliation". [Best practices for recommending a web app or other tool](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4059/88163) does not state that it is compulsory to mention "I have no affiliation" if one has no affiliations with a product/service/app/etc. one recommends, so I'd like to understand why a moderator deleted the answer because "[The OP] should disclose your affiliation".

Is it compulsory to mention "I have no affiliation" if one has no affiliations with a product/service/app/etc. one recommends?

Comment: Related: [I’ve been wrongly accused of spamming, and my answer has been deleted and marked as spam, costing me 100 rep](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4957/7584)